# a basic doubt on continuous image of a measurable set measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Is continuous image (say the function is on $\Bbb R^n$) of a measurable set measurable ? Hint enough. Actually, $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is given to be linear. I used some theorem to conclude that it is continuous.

Comment: I can't give you a counterexample, but I think I read somewhere that continuous image of a measurable set needs not be measurable. It is however true for a linear image

Comment: The usual counterexample is to take the [Cantor Function](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCantor_function&ei=dhX5UuDRL4Px0wGpuYCAAQ&usg=AFQjCNG38sLH2fRzudzqaMqrGqe0W4sXWA&bvm=bv.60983673,d.dmQ) ϕ and define ψ(x)=x+ϕ(x). ψ is one-to-one and maps the measure-zero Cantor set onto a set A of positive measure. Now consider the inverse of ψ and a non-measurable subset of A. c.f. Gelbaum and Olmsted, Counterexamples in Analysis, example 8.16. (I'm  assuming you're using Lebesgue mesure here.)

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki,@David: How to prove that linear image of a measurable set is measurable ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer in the case that the set is Lebesgue measurable and $f$ is Lipschitz.

Suppose $f$ is Lipschitz with rank $L$, and use the $\max$ norm for convenience. Let $S$ be an open 'square', that is, $S=\Pi_k I$ for a bounded interval $I=(a,b)$. Since $S = \cup_i S_i$, where $S_i = \Pi_k [a+{1 \over i}, b-{1 \over i}] $, we have $f(S) = \cup_i f(S_i)$, and since each $S_i$ is compact, we have $f(S_i)$ is compact and hence measurable. It follows that $f(S)$ is measurable. Since we can write an open 'rectangle' $R$ as the countable union of squares, we see that $f(R)$ is measurable as well.

Then if we let $x=({a+b \over 2}, ..., {a+b \over 2})$, and $y \in S$, then $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le L \|x-y\| < L ( {b-a \over 2})$
and so $f(S) \subset B(f(x), L({b-a \over 2}))$.
It follows that $m(f(S)) \le L^n m(S)$. Since we can write an open rectangle as the countable union of squares, we have $m(f(R)) \le L^n m(R)$ for any open rectangle $R$. It follows that $\cup_k R_k$ is also measurable and $m(f(\cup_k R_k)) \le \sum_k m(f (R_k)) \le L^n \sum_k m(R_k)$.

**Key fact**:
Suppose $f$ is Lipschitz and the set $N$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Then for any $n>0$ there is a collection of open rectangles $R_k$ such that $N \subset \cup_k R_k$ and $\sum_n m R_k < \epsilon$. Since $f(N) \subset f(\cup_k R_k)$, we see that $m^*(f(N)) < L^n \epsilon$, where $m^*$ is the outer measure. It follows that $m^*(f(N)) = 0$ and since the Lebesgue measure is complete, we have that $f(N)$ is measurable and $m(f(N))=0$.

Now suppose $A$ is measurable. Then there is a $F_\sigma$ set $F$ such that $F \subset A$ and $m(A \setminus F) = 0$ (note that from above, we have that $f(A \setminus F)$ is measurable). We can write $F = \cup_i F_i$, where each $F_i$ is compact. As above, since $f$ is continuous we  have $f(F_i)$ is compact, hence measurable. It follows that $f(F) = f(\cup_i F_i) = \cup_i f(F_i)$ is measurable, and since $A = F \cup (A \setminus F)$, we have $f(A) = f(F) \cup f(A \setminus F)$, the union of two measurable sets, hence $f(A)$ is measurable.

It follows from the above that $m(f(A)) \le L^n m(A)$.

Since any linear map on a finite dimensional space is Lipschitz, we see that a linear map maps measurable sets to measurable sets.

Comment: I could not understand this "Then if we let $x=({a+b \over 2}, ..., {a+b \over 2})$, and $y \in S$, then $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le L \|x-y\| < L ( {b-a \over 2})$
and so $f(S) \subset B(f(x), L({b-a \over 2}))$.
It follows that $m(f(S)) \le L m(S)$." Why lipschitz condition implies the last two lines. What is the $B$ function ?

Comment: If $y \in S$, then $y_i \in (a,b)$ and so $|y_i -{1+b \over 2}| < {b-a \over 2}$. Hence $\|x-y\| < {b-a \over 2}$, and since $f$ is Lipschitz you get the bound on $f(S)$. Hence $f(y) \in B(f(x), L({b -a \over 2})$.

Comment: Oops, I should have $L^n$ for the bound.

Comment: So $m(S) = m(B(x,{b-a \over 2})) = (b-a)^n$, and $m(f(S)) \le m(B(f(x), L ( { b-a \over 2})) = L^n(b-a)^n$, hence $m(f(S)) \le L^n f(S)$.

Comment: What is the $B$ function ?

Comment: $B(x,\epsilon) = \{ y | \|x-y\| < \epsilon \}$.