Is it true that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $ B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a borel set, then $f(B)$ is a borel set?
I'm pretty sure this is false and that I should use Cantor's function (its extension) as a counterexample, but I don't know how.

See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671173/a-basic-doubt-on-continuous-image-of-a-measurable-set-measurable

For the benefit of OP, let me mention that David Mitra (in a comment)  gave a counter-example in above link.

@Oscar thank you!

@geetha290krm thank you too!

actually I'm sorry @Oscar, but I dont understand how the counterxample given by David Mitra works in this case, because it proves that $\exists D$ nonmeasurable (hence non borel) such that $\varphi^{-1}(D)$ is measurable, but I don't know if $\varphi^{-1}(D)$ is a borel set with certainty, right?

@Oscar: But your answer only demonstrates that the set $\phi^{-1}(D)$ is Lebesgue measurable, by invoking the completeness of the Lebesgue measure. That does not show that the set is Borel measurable.

@LeeMosher That's a good point. I completely missed the fact that we require the set to be Borel. I will edit the answer. Thanks!

It is good question. In general the statement is false. However, if $f$ is injecitve then images of Borel sets are Borel again. If $f$ is just continuous, then images of Borel sets are analytic and thus still Lebesgue measurable, but not necessarily Borel.

Here is a brief counterexample (although the construction is more complicated than just using Cantor's function).
As is somewhat more well known, under the projection function
$$p : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1] \qquad p(x,y)=x
$$
there exists a Borel subset $B \subset [0,1] \times [0,1]$ such that $p(B)$ is not Borel. See this math.stackexchange question for an example.
Suppose now that $g : [0,1] \to [0,1] \times [0,1]$ is a continuous surjective function, for example the Peano curve. Let $D = g^{-1}(B)$ and let $f = p \circ g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous, it follows that $D \subset [0,1]$ is a Borel set, but $f(D)=p(B)$ is not a Borel set.

For a bit of historical background, see this answer in the same post as above. In brief, Lebesgue himself made the mistake of asserting that the continuous image of a Borel set is a Borel set, and Souslin discovered a counterexample. This gave rise to a new branch of mathematics, descriptive set theory and the theory of analytic sets and the projective hierarchy, which is all closely tied to logic. The set $p(B)$ is an example of an analytic set which is not Borel.

Thank you a lot! The historical background is really interesting too, I'll be looking into it, thanks again.
